# Slow packet transfer rate iOS BLE

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, throughput, packet-loss

The problem I've observed is that sending for example 100 packets took about 50 seconds which is much longer than expected.

If I tried sending packets without a delay, I realized that `CBPeripheralManager` `updateValue:forCharacteristic:onSubscribedCentrals:` returned `BOOL` value `NO` indicating packet was not sent, likely because underlying transmit queue is full.

I tried fixing this by resending the packet when queue space becomes available via `peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers`, but it still takes around 30 seconds to send 100 packets - with no delay mechanism.

What do I need to consider or change if trying to reduce the duration to around 10 seconds as expected?

By the way, the connection parameters `interval` is set to 125 milliseconds with 0 latency.

Comment: If you need to send large amounts of data then [L2Cap](https://github.com/paulw11/L2Cap) may be a better option, but both sides of your connection need to support it.

Comment: @Paulw11 I see, I'll look into that more. But I think It should still be possible to achieve higher speed than this. purpose for doing so is more for testability of packet error rate